# Insert Image into SSRS Report using Pathname from Dataset

Tags: sql, image, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I am looking to insert an external image, saved within a local drive, into an SSRS report.

At the moment I have this as the Value expression of the Image:

```
="file:" + First(Fields!IMGs.Value, "DataSet1")
```

The value of the field is the location of the image I want to display held within a local drive and typically looks like:

```
"C:\TEST\IMGs\THIS-01.jpg"
```

Essentially the combined string should read as :

```
"file:C:\TEST\IMGs\THIS-01.jpg"
```

I have also tried replacing the single slashes with double slashes to no avail. So essentially, is this possible and if so where am I going wrong? (as the image is not displaying.)

Comment: Image file paths are not valid. SSRS supports embedded images, images stored on the database and http URL's

Comment: This is not true. External image paths can be used to display images. See as per this TechBrothersIT video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umKjZKh4vVo

Comment: Things change! In the video  it uses double backslash for the path. Also check if SSRS service account has permissions in the folder

Comment: I have used both double and single backslash to no avail, unfortunately :(

Comment: Maybe it has to do with permissions

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what this could be? Are there settings within SSRS or my local drive?

Comment: Its on the folder properties. Go to security tab and check if SSRS service user is on the list with read permissions. To find with which user the service is running, use Reporting Services configuration manager and check the Web Service Identity tab

Answer (score 0):

In Report Data (ctr+Alt+D),[image] you can see Images tab.Add the image there and drag it to the report where ever you needed.

Comment: I cannot use embedded images as the images within the local drive are deleted and reuploaded from a VBA application with purpose.I am going to change the local drive to a network drive later in development. I am looking to use the pathname opposed to saving the image within SSRS

Comment: Okay. Keep path in this format:
file:D:\TV1.jpg and dont use ""

Comment: You may also need to set external image as Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = True
before the report is being refreshed                                                                                                   Also, you can try to implement this using the full network path as follows
file:\\servername\folder\mypicture.jpg

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

In the Image, 'Select the image source' as 'External' and in 'Use this Image' add the expression as ="file:\"+Parameters!Photo.Value(this is a parameter added by me).

Add a Parameter 'Photo'

Parameter Properties

General-> DataType-> Text

Available Values ->
    select 'Get values from a query'
     DataSet ->you dataset name
     value field-> select the path field from your query
     Name-> any name

While displaying the report in the preview panel, they will ask to select the Photo parameter value.